# ASP.NET Send email via Google smtp

Tags: asp.net

I've to send registration e-mail, after form SUBMIT. I've surf on google documentation, but i don't understand if there are a way to use Google Servers to send. 
Help me with a code if possible.
Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help before asking.

Comment: Quickly searching Google yields this as the first hit: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/254743/sending-email-in-asp-net-using-smtp-gmail-server

Answer (score 1):

[Reference](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/11/introduction-this-article-i-will.html)

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
// Sender e-mail address.
Msg.From = txtFrom.Text;
// Recipient e-mail address.
Msg.To = txtTo.Text;
Msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
Msg.Body = txtBody.Text;
// your remote SMTP server IP.
SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "10.20.72.1";
SmtpMail.Send(Msg);
Msg = null;
Page.RegisterStartupScript("UserMsg", "<script>alert('Mail sent thank you...');if(alert){ window.location='SendMail.aspx';}</script>");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
}
}
```